# How to click on the element with text as Gmail by Google on google search result page using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I was coding my first selenium java script as below.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class testClass {
    WebDriver driver;
    

    public void launchBrowser() throws InterruptedException {   
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
        "C:\\Users\\acer\\Downloads\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        
    }
    
    private void sendData() throws InterruptedException {
        WebElement we1 = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        we1.sendKeys("GMAIL");
        we1.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(2000); 
        we1.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Gmail by Google']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000); 

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        testClass obj=new testClass();
        obj.launchBrowser();
        obj.sendData();
        

    }

}
```

It gives no error. But

```
we1.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Gmail by Google']")).click();
```

is not working. It does not click on **Gmail by Google**. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The text **Gmail by Google** is within a child `<h3>` tag of the ancestor `<a>` tag.

[image: GmailByGoogle]

So instead of:

```
we1.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Gmail by Google']")).click();
```

You need to use:

```
we1.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[text()='Gmail by Google']")).click();
```

Comment: @MalshaMadushani That's because the timeframe of `Thread.sleep(2000);` is way too short for the timespan between `sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)` and the following `we1.findElement()`. You need to increase the timeframe.

Comment: ```Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//h3[text()='Gmail by Google']}
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)```

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("GMAIL");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Gmail by Google")).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

Links can be accessed using an exact or partial match of their link text

so when you want to click on any element than first check any link is there or not. If link is there then it's better you can use LinkText or partialLinkText

here i see same thing

```
we1.findElement(By.LinkText("https://www.google.com/gmail/")).click();
```

Comment: @NicoHaase hope so now everybody can understand  
Thank You.